# keep fragment used in xml during obfuscation?

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, android-proguard

I have been getting complaints from my users that my app crashes on certain devices (Not on all) and I havent been able to reproduce this issue while testing on more than 15 devices but I realized that when I remove proguard obfuscation the app doesnt crash any more now I got some logs from my users and even though the main cause can not be found in the log I realized it is happening in an activity where there is a fragment tag in the xml like this :

```
   <fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.example.fragment" />
```

now I wanted to know if this could cause an error on some devices ? Do I need to add the `com.example.fragment` to the proguard rules ? or does proguard handle this automatically?

Comment: Did you find a good solution for it? Now I just keep this file in proguard, but it is not cool